# How to translate “facing right”

Tags: phrase-requests

Imagine I want to describe this photo and I want to say something like “the cat is facing right”, ie, his head is turned towards the right-hand side of the image.

[image: a cute cat looking towards the right of the picture]

Some ideas I had:

- La kato frontas la dekstran flankon de la bildo.

According to [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#fronti_kd) *fronti* is more about being ready for a fight or facing a challenge, so it’s probably not appropriate.

- La kato turniĝas dekstren.

I think this would apply some sort of motion. I don’t think that would make sense here because the cat is just chilling.

- La kato rigardas dekstren.

This could work, but it wouldn’t apply for a more general translation of the English phrase. For example when talking about the direction that a house faces.

Comment: Laŭ mia opinio, oni povas plibonigi la duan proponon per participo: “La kato estas turnita dekstren” aŭ “Kato turnita dekstren”. Oni ankoraŭ povus pensi ke okazis ia movo, sed *turnita* pli bone priskribas *staton* ol *turniĝas* (simile al *fermita*, kvankam oni povus kompreni ke okazis la ago fermi, oni ja uzas *fermita* por priskribi simplan staton).

Comment: @marcus Tio havas sencon, jes, dankon. Kaj ĝi kongruas kun laŭvorta traduko de la originala franca frazo kiun mi volis traduki.

Answer (score 3):

`La kato rigardas dekstren` estas bone priskriba. Alia ebla solvo estus [`-n` por pozicio](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/aliaj_signifoj.html#i-v4u).

> N-finaĵo estas sufiĉe ofte uzata por montri pozicion de parto (ofte korpoparto).

```
Kato (ago) kun la kapo dekstren
```

Aŭ, pri domo:

```
Domo kun pordo norden
```

`fronti` ne estas nepre aŭ ĉefe *lukta* kaj oni povas ĝin uzi en tiu ĉi situacio. Aferoj povas fronti kontraŭ aliaj aferoj, nur pozicie.

La precipe luktan signifon enkondukas `alfronti`, kiu cetere estas konvene transitiva (`fronti`, malgraŭ la amaso da aperoj en Tekstaro kun rekta objekto, estas netransitiva).

`rigardi` estas sufiĉe ampleksa kaj ankaŭ uzebla. Domo povas rigardi norden sen probleme. Tiu estas la sepa signifo, [laŭ la nuna PIV](https://vortaro.net/#rigardi_kdc):

> 7 Esti turnita en iu direkto: la vilaĝo trans la lagon rigardas al la mondvojo (Z); fenestro rigardanta al la korto (Z)

Inter tiuj ebloj mi pensas ke

```
rigardi + direkta vorto + n, do:

  La kato rigardas dekstren
```

estas traduko kaj bona kaj simpla, tre verŝajne preferinda.

Comment: Dankon pro la respondo. Jes verŝajne, _rigardi_ ja taŭgas do. Mi tamen pensas ke povus esti konfuze ke ĝi havas tiujn du sencojn. Ekzemple en la unua bildo de ĉi tiu konata memeo, la fronto de la simio rigardas dekstren, sed liaj okuloj rigardas maldekstren. https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/awkward-look-monkey-puppet

Comment: Tiuokaze vi dirus "simio kiu rigardas maldekstren kun kapo dekstren". Ankaŭ en kelkaj aliaj lingvoj kiu akceptas `rigardi ion` kiel `kun la "antaŭa" parto turnita al io`.

Answer (score 1):

`fronto` with antonym `dorso` have the same meaning in Esperanto as in English (to face) with respect to a building (`konstruaĵo`) for instance (Reta-Vortaro).

The definitions of `fronti` and `alfronti` seem *overspecified* - with respect to its fundamental meaning.

> Sin turni prezentante fronton kontraŭ io aŭ iu <del>por batali</del>.

A better definition would be:

> Prezenti sian fronton kontraŭ (al) io aŭ iu.

Overspecification or exemplification, using a specific case, rather often happens.
Here the verb clearly overspecifies.

- La domo ne frontas la straton.
- La domo ne rigardas al la strato.

Above `rigardas` is officially correct; where you hesitated. However I find it a rare non-literal usage, and `rigardi dekstren` and `fronti dekstre` are different in that in `fronti` the subject is turned in the direction of the object.

One could avoid the formal issue with the verb `fronti` using the substantive:

- La fronto de la kato estas en la dekstra direkto.

Comment: If _fronti_ can be used in that way then it seems like the ideal solution to me because it doesn’t have the confusing double meaning that _rigardi_ has. PIV is weird in that the definition explicitly says that it is for _batali_, but then it has an example with a house and a park. So I guess we’re supposed to understand that the house is going to fight the park? Maybe it would be good to try to get the dictionaries updated to reflect the actual usage.

Comment: It has been said that PIV has somekind of an agenda and therefore in many cases overspecifies words. In contrast Reta vortaro reflects actual use without criticism and therefore contains outright errors. So there are no perfect solutions.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas thanks, enlightening. It would have been nice to have arrive at one single specific defnition, hopefully sufficient disambiguate, and use case exaple (enemy here).